# No ACK recieved in Gun.js

Tags: javascript, gun

I am using Gun.js and on load I am putting a value in.

This is for a new website, and I have already tried making everything when the page loads instead of just in a script tag.

```
        var mid = Date.now().toString() + "and" + (Math.round(Math.random()) + Math.round(Math.random())).toString();
        var gun = Gun('https://gunjs.herokuapp.com/gun');
        gun.get(`tictac/toe${mid}`).put({
            "type": "test"
        });
```

I expect it not to produce an error, but it is producing an error:

`{err: "Error: No ACK received yet.", lack: true}`

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

@Mikey ,

`No ACK received yet` `lack: true` means that GUN has not received an acknowledgement that the data was correctly saved. This means your data may not be backed up.

Often times this happens because on other peers someone is running GUN as `require('gun/gun')` which does NOT include default storage adapters. On other (non-browser) peers, you should include GUN as `require('gun')` which DOES include default adapters (transport, storage, etc.).

In this case, it looks like you are connected to a testing peer (gunjs.herokuapp), please note that this is not for production use cases, and could be part of the problem.

For us to figure out what is going wrong, I highly encourage you to join our super friendly community ( https://gitter.im/amark/gun ) to help you out.

Comment: I am not using node to require gun, I am just using the GitHub repo.